# Linux freezes randomly on AMD

Tags: kubuntu, freeze, 32-bit, fedora

I'm getting constant freezes on Linux.
I've tried Kubuntu 19.10 with KDE and Zorin with gnome. Now I'm using Fedora 32 with KDE and it happens in all of them.

I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> to use a terminal, and I can't use the mouse.

I've noticed that the freeze **always occurs when I'm using a browser**, so I disabled hardware acceleration, but I keep getting the freezes. (If it's useful for something, the browsers I've used: Firefox and Chrome)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> doesn't work well, it get stuck on the KDE loading screen

[**REISUB**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses) solution works, but I'm wondering if there's a way that doesn't involve rebooting and having to start all the stuff I had again. I want to find the source of the problem and I do think it has something to do with the browser, but I haven't managed to get anything.

My laptop details are:

- Acer Swift SF315-41
- AMD Ryzen 7 2700U
- Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx

Comment: When your laptop "freezes" can you `ssh` into it from another device/laptop and diagnose the issue?

Comment: Could be a hardware problem or old BIOS. While you may have tried Kubuntu at some point, the problem is hardly related.